# Flink join operator not showing any output

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Im new to Flink. I got two DataStreams and i want to apply a keyed join in a tumbling Window. All the code works fine but the join never gives any result. I even apply `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` on the joined Datastreams and on `fromSource`

```
KafkaSource<ConsumerRecord> iotA = KafkaSource.<ConsumerRecord>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers(IP)
                .setTopics("iotA")
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
                .setDeserializer(KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema.of(new KafkaDeserializationSchema<ConsumerRecord>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean isEndOfStream(ConsumerRecord record) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public ConsumerRecord deserialize(ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record) throws Exception {
                        String key = new String(record.key(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        String value = new String(record.value(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        return new ConsumerRecord(
                                record.topic(),
                                record.partition(),
                                record.offset(),
                                record.timestamp(),
                                record.timestampType(),
                                record.checksum(),
                                record.serializedKeySize(),
                                record.serializedValueSize(),
                                key,
                                value
                        );
                    }

                    @Override
                    public TypeInformation<ConsumerRecord> getProducedType() {
                        TypeInformation<ConsumerRecord> typeInfo = TypeInformation.of(ConsumerRecord.class);
                        return typeInfo;
                    }
                }))
                .build();
        KafkaSource<ConsumerRecord> iotB = //same as iotA
   
        DataStream<ConsumerRecord> iotA_datastream = env.fromSource(iotA,
                WatermarkStrategy.<ConsumerRecord>forMonotonousTimestamps()
                .withTimestampAssigner((record, timestamp) -> record.timestamp()), "Kafka Source");
    
        DataStream<ConsumerRecord> iotB_datastream = //same as iotA_datastream

        DataStream<ConsumerRecord> mapped_iotA = iotA_datastream.map(new MapFunction<ConsumerRecord, ConsumerRecord>() {
            @Override
            public ConsumerRecord map(ConsumerRecord record) throws Exception {
                String new_value = splitValue((String) record.value(), 0);
                return new ConsumerRecord(record.topic(), record.partition(), record.offset(), record.timestamp(), record.timestampType(),
                        record.checksum(), record.serializedKeySize(), record.serializedValueSize(), record.key(), new_value);
            }
        }).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy.<ConsumerRecord>forMonotonousTimestamps()
                .withTimestampAssigner((record, timestamp) -> record.timestamp()));

        DataStream<ConsumerRecord> mapped_iotB = //same as mapped_iotA

        DataStream<String> joined_stream= mapped_iotA.join(mapped_iotB)
                .where(new KeySelector<ConsumerRecord, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String getKey(ConsumerRecord record) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println((String) record.key()+record.value());
                        return (String) record.key();
                    }
                })
                .equalTo(new KeySelector<ConsumerRecord, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String getKey(ConsumerRecord record) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println((String) record.key()+record.value());
                        return (String) record.key();
                    }
                })
                .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
                .apply(new JoinFunction<ConsumerRecord, ConsumerRecord, String> (){
                    @Override
                    public String join(ConsumerRecord record1, ConsumerRecord record2) throws Exception {//doesnt show anything
                        System.out.println("value1" + record1.value() + "value2" + record2.value());
                        return "null";
                    }
                        });

        env.execute();
```

I also tried with other Watermark Strategies like `forBoundedOutOfOrderness` and wider windows time with the same result

Answer (score 1):

Try attaching a sink to the job. E.g.,

```java
DataStream<String> joined_stream= mapped_iotA.join(mapped_iotB)
  ...

joined_stream.print();
env.execute();
```

Comment: didnt work. I noticed that every event is executing the getKey method inside the join operator twice and i dont know why

Comment: How much data are you testing with? Both streams will have to advance past the end of the window in order to trigger the join.

Comment: Currently I'm manually sending two or three records (using the default kafka producer) on each stream to test with no luck

Comment: Then, i tried waiting for more than 5 minutes and nothing happens

Comment: That won’t work. You must have events from both streams in one window and the next window.

Comment: You mean a continuous flow of data?

Comment: Not necessarily. But you do need to process at least one event from each stream in the same window, so that the join can produce a result, and at least one event from each stream with timestamps beyond that window, so that the window becomes complete and will be triggered.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I'm sorry:(

Comment: If your test data includes events for a window for the interval from 12:00:00 to 12:00:05 (exclusive), that window might not produce results unless the test data also includes at least one event at or after 12:00:05 for each of the two streams. (Whether or not this is necessary depends on how the testing is being done.)

Comment: Hello David and thank you for your patience!
I think I meet the requirements you mention, so I think the problem is something else.